# C, variable initialization

Tags: c, variables

This code is supposed to read certain amount of numbers and then print how many of them are divisible by the divisor variable, however when i write it like this there seems to be some kind of problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long repeat;
    int divisor;
    long long t;
    long result = 0;

    scanf("%d", &repeat);
    scanf("%d", &divisor);


    for (long i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &t);
        if (t % divisor == 0)
        {
            result++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d",result);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I set all of the variables at the start to 0 it works fine. Can somebody tell me what´s the problem with the first implementation?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long repeat = 0;
    int divisor = 0;
    long long t = 0;
    long result = 0;

    scanf("%d", &repeat);
    scanf("%d", &divisor);


    for (long i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &t);
        if (t % divisor == 0)
        {
            result++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d",result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `long long t; .... 
        scanf("%d", &t);` should generate a warning.  Insure all warnings are enabled and report the results.   This will save you time.

Comment: "...there seems to be some kind of problem."  That isn't very descriptive.  What sort of problem?  An error?  Unexpected output?  It's hard to identify what might be wrong, especially when you aren't showing any examples of the values you are feeding in.

Comment: The result is always 0.

Comment: Perhaps read the manual page for scanf.  It returns a value that you should check

Comment: I don´t get any warning messages.

Comment: What are you using to compile?

Comment: The answer has already been given by chux: Wrong format specifier when reading `t`. After that it's all UB.

Comment: I'm getting the warnings using cc: https://imgur.com/a/2X4g06H

Comment: You´re right it´s the format specifier. Thanks for help. Idk why my compiler doesn´t show any warnings.

Comment: Im using the newest mingw gcc.

Comment: @PřemekBělka For gcc use `-Wall` to get all warnings

Comment: @PřemekBělka BTW: When using `scanf` always, always, **always** check the return value. Like: `if (scanf("%d", &repeat) != 1) { // error handling.... exit(1);}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not someone, but some**thing** - GCC 7.2 **can**:

```
% gcc div.c -Wall -Wextra
div.c: In function ‘main’:
div.c:10:13: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, 
          but argument 2 has type ‘long int *’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d", &repeat);
            ~^   ~~~~~~~
            %ld
div.c:16:17: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, 
          but argument 2 has type ‘long long int *’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%d", &t);
                ~^   ~~
                %lld
div.c:23:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, 
          but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%d",result);
             ~^
             %ld
```

It also tells below **what** you should use **instead**: `%ld`, `%lld` and `%ld`. Since you didn't use correct length modifiers, the **behaviour** was **undefined**, which made you think that you "fixed" the program by initializing the variables with zeroes.

---

Also, remember to check the return value of `scanf` and that you need to discard for example the rest of the line if something invalid has been input; just entering `hello` into your program will make it hang.